# Search record from database and display value in textbox and drop downlist

Tags: c#, database

Below is my code for a search button. When I search the record of student, the value is displayed in text fields but not in dropdownnlist. What is the reason fpr this?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Final Project\FinalProject\FinalProject\App_Data\Record.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

try
{
    string query = "select * from student where StdId='" + txtID.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = null;

    con.Open();
    reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        txtfirstname.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
        txtlastname.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
        txtfaname.Text = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
        txtfcellno.Text = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
        txtfnic.Text = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
        txthome.Text = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();

        drpclassno.Text = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();
        drpgender.Text = reader.GetValue(10).ToString();
        drpday.Text = reader.GetValue(11).ToString();
        drpmonth.Text = reader.GetValue(12).ToString();
        drpyear.Text = reader.GetValue(13).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "Record was not Found...!";
    }
```

Comment: Are any exceptions being thrown?. Since you did not tell us what technology you are using for your UI and you did not show any definition of the actual drop down control it is very hard to help you any further. Sometime erratic UI behavior is being caused by the editing thread not being the owner of the control, i.e. the UI thread

Comment: How many tables are in your database?  Either the columns 9 to 13 are empty or the data is in another table and your query need to join multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

The used technology here seems to be ASP.NET, because the `DropDownList` in Windows Forms/WPF is called `ComboBox`.

You assign values, that are not in the source of the list.

To assign a value to a `DropDownList` it have to be in its `DataSource`:

```
drpclassno.DataSource = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
drpclassno.DataBind();
drpclassno.Text = "3"; // Works, because its in the Source

drpclassno.DataSource = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
drpclassno.DataBind();
drpclassno.Text = "4"; // Does not work
```

You can also use `SelectedValue` property instead of `Text` to make your intention clearer.